# How to use RSA for licence key?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I'm trying to create a licence key for my application and I was reading about RSA.

The user of my application should type a code and the code will be deciphered to check whether the user has access to the application or not.

What I understood so far is that RSA has two keys, the public one to encrypt data and the private to decrypt data.

In my case, I want to avoid having a key stored at the application and that can be found easily by a hacker.

But according to the RSA the decrypting key should be private and will be used to decrypt data.

Does anyone know how can I avoid storing the private key in the application please ? Am I missing something ?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You'd need to use signatures, which in the case of RSA are at least 100 bytes. Not something your user will want to type. With DSA/ECDSA signatures you get down to around 30 bytes. With fancy BLS signatures (hard to find implementations for it), you get around 15 bytes.

Comment: And of course, no matter how fancy your crypto, an attacker can always patch your application to remove the key validation. This only prevents key generators, not cracks.

Comment: Typing the key is a detail... I plan to create a file with the code in it no matter the size of the code... So the size of the code doesn't really bother me. And again I'm not trying to make my app uncrackable which is impossible (I know). I'm just trying to avoid the first level of hacking which is storing a key in the application. Any ideas please ?

Comment: If you're fine with large codes, simply use RSA *signatures*, not RSA *encryption*. That way the application can verify using the public key and sign using the private key.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Verification using the public key and signing using the private key. Do you have a link on that ? I couldn't find any interesting article. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton, have you tried googling for "RSA signature"? [A general introduction to digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature), a concrete algorithm name to look for in cryptography libraries: "RSASSA-PSS" or "RSA PSS" from the [PKCS 1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA-PSS), [a C++ library with an RSA signature scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_r_s_a_s_s.html), [a Java signature tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple XML format for a license, with some identifying information in the XML. Then you can add an XML signature using *your favorite XML library here* with your RSA key pair.

The "code" is the simple XML text file, complete with XML signature in it. Just be careful the newlines in the text file are not converted when the file is transported.

The public key is embedded in the application, which can then verify the signature on the license file and use any information carried in the XML. You keep the private key tucked safely in your safe -- you just need to bring it out to sign more licenses.